# useing several List<T> as Request in servicestack

Tags: generics, request, servicestack

When I use several `List<T>` as request,several `List`1` appeared on the metadata page. So this is not unique and can not view the operation.

```cs
Routes.Add<List<Class1>>("/Class1/BatchSave")
  .Add<List<Class2>>("/Class2/BatchSave")
  .Add<List<Class3>>("/Class3/BatchSave");
```

But the operation names on the metadata page are all `List`1`. When I view the operation detail, it's throw an Exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only register Request DTOs on routes, e.g:

```
Routes.Add<Class1>("/Class1/BatchSave")
  .Add<Class2>("/Class2/BatchSave")
  .Add<Class3>("/Class3/BatchSave");
```

Although Request DTOs can inherit collections, e.g:

```
public class Class1 : List<string> { }
```